# Ubuntu 19.04 won't connect via Ethernet

Tags: networking, internet, ethernet, 19.04

I just built a custom PC with Windows 10 installed on one SSD, and Ubuntu 19.04 on another SSD. My Windows OS connects to the internet just fine via Ethernet, but Ubuntu absolutely refuses to connect. This is a fresh install of 19.04.

I've read a ton of forums online, both on this site and others, and tried many solutions, including editing the `/etc/network/interfaces` file, the `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` file, messing around with the `resolv.conf` and related files, changing `ifupdown` settings, and absolutely nothing works. I installed the `r8168`driver using a flash drive in the hopes it would work, but nothing happens. I bypassed my router and connected Ethernet cable directly from modem to computer: nothing. For some reason, Ubuntu will not receive any DNS information. It's not a faulty Ethernet cable since Windows works just fine. I'm at my wit's end about what to do.

For information, I'm using:

- Ubuntu 19.04
- AMD Ryzen 9 processor
- Asus ROG Crosshair VIII Hero (Wi-Fi) motherboard

I'm no stranger to Linux/Ubuntu, having used it for years. Also, my Ubuntu install is separate from my Windows install, and I'm very comfortable in the command line, so I don't mind messing around with files or settings that might have adverse effects, as I have another OS to fall back on if something gets corrupted. Could anyone provide any insight?

Edit:

Result of `sudo lshw -C network`:

```
*-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:e000(size=256) memory:f7810000-f781ffff memory:f7820000-f7823fff memory:f7800000-f780ffff memory:f7830000-f789ffff memory:f78a0000-f78bbfff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: I211 Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: enp4s0
       version: 03
       serial: 04:d9:f5:87:39:10
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=igb driverversion=5.4.0-k firmware=0. 6-1 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:33 memory:f7700000-f771ffff ioport:d000(size=32) memory:f7720000-f7723fff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
       version: 1a
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f7600000-f7603fff
```

Result of `ls -al /etc/resolv.conf`:

```
lrwxrwrwx 1 root root 27 Sep 4 15:54 /etc/resolv.conf -> /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf
```

Result of `cat /etc/resolv.conf`:

```
cat: /etc/resolv.conf: No such file or directory
```

Result of `cat /etc/network/interfaces`:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
allow-hotplug enp4s0
iface enp4s0 inet dhcp
```

Result of `cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`:

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=false

[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

Result of `dkms status`: `dkms` is not installed on my system, and was prompted to install with `apt`

Result of `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`:

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
    version: 2
    renderer: NetworkManager
```

Comment: Edit your question and show me `ls -al /etc/resolv.conf` and `cat /etc/resolv.conf` and `sudo lshw -C network` and `cat /etc/network/interfaces` and `cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` and `dkms status`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: And `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`

Comment: @heynnema all requested commands added to the edit. Sorry if you were spammed with comments earlier. I was using a phone and had to type all these things out by hand.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Can you please redo `cat /etc/resolv.conf`? Also, how many physical ethernet ports are on this computer? Remove the two `enp4s0` lines from `/etc/network/interfaces`. Reboot and configure a "Wired Connection" using the NetworkManager GUI. Retry ethernet.

Comment: @heynnema there are two Ethernet ports on my motherboard: the 2.5Gbps port and the regular LAN port. Both ports are not working, but the regular LAN port is now displaying DNS information, albeit without any internet connection behind it. I removed the enp4s0 lines from `/etc/network/interfaces` but my wired connection in the NetworkManager UI (through the Settings app) is still displaying as enp4s0, and there are two entries for it. Also, `cat /etc/resolv.conf` still returns `No such file or directory`.

Comment: You have more than one problem here. I'd recommend just reinstalling Ubuntu again. Although, for testing, if you wish, you can boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB and see if the ethernet ports work then.